# Why is the transformer not receiving any AC voltage, and why is the LED not lighting up?

Tags: simulation, proteus

[image: Proteus simulation of electrical muscle stimulator using ic555]

I built an electrical muscle stimulator circuit to simulate in Proteus. I am not getting any AC voltage on the primary and secondary transformers and the LED (D1) doesn't light up either when I run it. What is the problem?

Comment: What waveform comes out of the Q pin on the 555? Will a 555 operate on a 3 volts supply?

Comment: @Andyaka I ran with a 6-volt supply and it operated on that.

Comment: But, even with a 6-volt supply, there was no change in the voltage levels of the transformers.

Comment: Maybe adjust RV1

Comment: There's still no signal even after I varied rv1 from 50 to 100. There was no mistake with the circuit, right?

Comment: Have you physically built this circuit, or are you only asking about the simulation?

Comment: Are the two pins VCC and DC of U1 really connected to the rest of the circuit.? The corresponding dots are not in place.

Comment: @brhans I have not built it physically at the moment, but I am planning to once the simulation starts working.

Comment: @Elec1 yes I have connected two pins to the rest of the circuit, But I will cross check it

Comment: I suggest you clean up that schematic before trying the sim again. Many of those wire junction dots look very suspicious - there are dots in places I wouldn't expect to see any (for example the bottom or 4 and Q1's emitter), and some weirdly placed ones (for example on both sides of R2). Also move that 'Ground' symbol somewhere sensible, like below the battery, instead of that random spot up at the top.